# The Async pipe not trigger even when getter of observable is called

Tags: angular, asynchronous, pipe, observable

I have a question. Maybe one of you can help me. I have a situation when async pipe in component not trigger even then subscription get of this observable is triggering (component not reviving changed value in `ngOnChanges`).

Code is like this:

html:

```html
<app-component [values]="values$ | async"></app-component>
```

ts:

```js
values$: Observable<ISomeValue[]> = this.service.getValue$();
```

service:

```js
private valuesBSubject: BehaviorSubject<ISomeValue[]> = new BehaviorSubject<ISomeValue[]>(this.defaultValues);
    
getValues$(): Observable<ISomeValue[]> {
    return this.valuesBSubject.asObservable();
}
    
setValues(values: ISomeValue[]): void {
    this.valuesBSubject.next(values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I think the input doesn't get the change because it's the same array object. I fixed it sending a new array to observable. Try this:

```js
setValues(values: ISomeValue[]): void {
   this.valuesBSubject.next([...values]);
}
```